# SCJP exam: Handle Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I'm studying for Java Programmer Certification (SCJP) exam. A question about exceptions, when handle exceptions is it best to handle a specific exception like `NumberFormatException` or catch all exceptions use the parent `Exception` `class`?

Base on my course unchecked exceptions are basically a `RunTimeException` which mostly result of a program bug. Does this mean that when I throw an exception manually I should rather use:

```
new Exception("... my message...")
```

and that I shouldn't handle `RunTimeException`?
Only handle checked exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle as specific `Exception`s as possible.  If you know when a `RuntimeException` may be thrown, you should usually fix your program so it doesn't throw that `Exception`.

As far as catching checked `Exceptions` go, you should handle as specific an `Exception` as you can so:

```
try {
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){
} catch (IOException ioe){
} catch (Exception e){
}
```

When you are throwing `Exceptions`, you should almost never use `throw new Exception()`.
Throw an exception that can give someone who sees it some more information about what happened when it was thrown. (i.e. `IndexOutOfBounds` or `NullPointerExceptions`.  They give specific info w/out even looking at the message or stacktrace.)

If you want to throw an `Exception`, and you don't think the Java API has one that fits your case, it is best to subclass or extend the Exception giving it a very informative name.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `Exception` (instead of `RuntimeException`) in those cases.